# I need to get an image src from the Xpath

Tags: python, xpath

[image]

I'm using Python to get some elements from a web page,
I need to get the SRC path from an Image tag using its Xpath code.

The Xpath I'm trying to get data from is the following:

```
//*[@id="product_24793"]/a/figure/img
```

I've already tried using these two formats for the Xpath

```
//*[@id="product_24793"]/a/figure/img/@src

//*[@id="product_24793"]/@src
```

Also the code that I have already tried is the following :

```
imgsrc = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="product_24793"]/a/figure/img')

for ele in imgsrc:
    print(ele.text)

path = ele.text
```

I'd like to have the src path as a result

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_attribute()` to fetch the `src` value.

```
imgsrc = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="product_24793"]/a/figure/img[@class="top"]')

for ele in imgsrc:
   print(ele.get_attribute('src'))
```